# Debugging programs run on QEMU with a GUI?

Tags: windows, debugging, user-interface, qemu

Is there an option to use a convenient debugger with a GUI for debugging programs run on QEMU on Windows? I know that QEMU has full support for GDB, yet I'm unable to find a good working GUI for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug QEMU that runs on Windows or Windows application in Windows VM that runs in QEMU use WinDbg: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx

You can also use Visual Studio express: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx and attach to process.

If you want to debug Windows kernel while Windows is a VM running inside of QEMU follow: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/GuestDebugging